# VLOOKUP Sum Multiple

Tags: excel, vba

The following code works but only finds the first occurance.

`=VLOOKUP(A2,'G:\Accounting\General\Audit Schedules\2013 Audit Schedule Info\[EX199 2013 II.xlsx]Sheet1'!I:T,10,FALSE)`

I need to find a way to sum Column R or return the LARGE occurance based on R. I am finding similar online but none use a second workbook and have been unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following formula for sum:

`=SUMPRODUCT(('G:\Accounting\General\Audit Schedules\2013 Audit Schedule Info\[EX199 2013 II.xlsx]Sheet1'!I:I = A2)*1, 'G:\Accounting\General\Audit Schedules\2013 Audit Schedule Info\[EX199 2013 II.xlsx]Sheet1'!R:R)`

Comment: Hm..`SUMIF` don't work with closed WB..Try now, I've updated answer